# Navigation drawer menu item with titles and sub titles

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, menuitem, subitem

I have a navigation drawer prototype. we have heading and subheading in the same. am using menu group to include the titles.

1) just want to add sub title or help text for the navigation drawer.
2) want to customise the icon size to fit the whole heading and sub heading so it looks like the image below.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:subtitle="View your biorhythm" <!-- This should be sub title. -->
        android:title="Home"
        />
```

[image: This is how a menu item should look like.]

Comment: what have you done so far..?

Comment: @Alok Rajasukumaran see my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside in `DrawerLayout` create `ListView` using below code

```
 <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

Now Create one `Class` that contain property for `Title`, `SubTitle` and `Icon` like below.

```
class NavItem {
    String mTitle;
    String mSubtitle;
    int mIcon;

    public NavItem(String title, String subtitle, int icon) {
        mTitle = title;
        mSubtitle = subtitle;
        mIcon = icon;
    }
}
```

Now Create `Adapter` for that

```
class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems;

    public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavItem> navItems) {
        mContext = context;
        mNavItems = navItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNavItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mNavItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView subtitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        titleView.setText( mNavItems.get(position).mTitle );
        subtitleView.setText( mNavItems.get(position).mSubtitle );
        iconView.setImageResource(mNavItems.get(position).mIcon);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Create `Listview` item xml to get your format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Finally Add into `MainActivity.java` file like below way.

```
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

ListView mDrawerList;
RelativeLayout mDrawerPane;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home", "Meetup destination", R.drawable.ic_action_home));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Preferences", "Change your preferences", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("About", "Get to know about us", R.drawable.ic_action_about));

    // DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
    mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Drawer Item click listeners
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItemFromDrawer(position);
        }
    });
```

You will get Below Output :

[image]

Comment: @Alok Rajasukumaran did you try my answer.

Comment: @Alok Rajasukumaran you can accept the answer if it helpful to you.

Comment: Ironman, I had found the original post, but finally ended up using a custom layout inside navigation drawer than using custom adaptor.

Comment: So the bets method is to use a custom layout and remove the menu xml, but you will have to capture the clicks on every layout yourself. Thanks for your valuble time ironman,!

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran glad to help you.