# How to add subtitle to material drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, menuitem, drawerlayout

I need to create material navigation drawer. I have already completed both header and menu with items. But I need to add this:

[image]

(in this example it is: " increase your limit") to the first item in drawer (this is just an design template).However, there is no parameter for aditional text...

My menu is in this typical format:

```
        <item
            android:id="@+id/blah"
            android:title="@string/blah"
            tools:icon="@drawable/blah" />

       <group
        android:id="@+id/drawer_group_primary"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/blah"

            android:title="@string/blah"
            tools:icon="@drawable/blah" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/blah"
            android:title="@string/blah"
            tools:icon="@drawable/blah" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/blah"
            android:title="@string/blah"
            tools:icon="@drawable/blah" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/blah"
            android:title="@string/blah"
            tools:icon="@drawable/blah" />
    </group>
```

I can add additional layout to item, but it looks like this:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa9BL.jpg) and i need to move that below title....

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/37936323/2435238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired layout, you should make changes in your `nav_header.xml`.  You can customize **nav_header** as you want, because you can implement viewgroups and views beside menu..

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said.

Answer (score -1):

You should probaly use Navigation view instead of drawer.
You could then use something like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and in the menu.xml you have to put this.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="Home" />
    ....
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
        android:title="Discussion" />
</group>

<item android:title="Sub items">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you. My question was not so clear. Actually, my solution was the same as yours. I knew how to add subtitle for group of items, but i needed to add subtitle for specific items (as it is on the  picture which i added.).